# Extending Dynamics CRM 2011 Service

Tags: wcf, service, dynamics-crm, crm, sample

I need to create a WCF service to extend what Dynamics CRM 2011 offers and be able to go beyond simple CRUD calls.  Are there any good tutorials or code samples covering this topic ?

Comment: The SDK is generally the first resource I go to, but what is it you need to do?

Comment: What model Dynamics CRM are you using - on-premise, online, or partner hosted?

Comment: I'm doing On-Premise.  As for what is it I want to do, I would like to do all the things you normally do when you expose a service layer which in the end performs activities on multiple entities based on business rules.  For starters, I need to implement an extended cloning function that allows to restrict fields and relationships if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another layer of web services on top of the built in CRM web services that is fine.  You will just need to create a normal asmx or WCF service, include the SDK DLLs, and perform the underlying CRUD operations to CRM within.  Similar question/answer here - http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/2c420566-cb9f-4d33-bb97-fea63f1843eb

Comment: I stated in my question that I have to create a WCF service, what I'm looking for is samples that work on CRM 2011.

Comment: The WCF service is only going to wrap the CRUD operations of the CRM services.  The code to communicate with CRM would be no different than any other SDK code that goes through the service.  I haven't seen any samples of WCF services used to connect to CRM 2011 yet.